# how to call cms page in anchor tag in phtml file

Tags: magento2

how to call cms page in anchor tag in phtml file any one help me I used below code but it  does not work.

```
     <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('wrapper'); ?>">wrapper</a>
```

Comment: It will create link like `http://www.example.com/wrapper/`. How you want ?

Comment: i want to call it in my header cusom link but it does not work

Comment: what URL you are getting ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have url key of your cms page

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl(' URL Key OF CMS PAGE ');?>">Link to my page</a>
```

or you can try with the cms page id, if you have id of your cms page then

```
$pageId = 1;
$this->_objectManager = $block->_objectManager;
$cmspageurl = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Cms\Helper\Page')
->getPageUrl($pageId);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$baseurl = $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_LINK);

<a href="<?php echo $baseurl.'cmspageurl'; ?>"> test </a>
```